# Present view when local notification is received

Tags: iphone, notifications, uilocalnotification

With iOS 5 and storyboarding, what is the best way to present a view when the user enters the app after having received a localnotification?

I have read that using the NSNotificationCenter is the way to do it but is that also so with storyboarding and segues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly how I implemented it. In the AppDelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method, I did the following:

```
   UILocalNotification *notification = 
   [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
   [self application:application didReceiveLocalNotification:notification];
```

I did this so that I could keep logic in a single place.  In the didreceiveLocalNotification: method, I then used the NSNotificationCenter:

```
    // Let another view handle the display        
    NSNotificationCenter * nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [nc postNotificationName:@"SHOW_VERSE" 
                      object:self 
                    userInfo:notification.userInfo];
```

The view that handles the display is the first UIViewController for the Storyboard.  In that class, in the viewDidLoad method:

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self  
                  selector:@selector(receivedLocalNotification:) 
                      name:@"SHOW_VERSE" 
                    object:nil];
```

This works very well for me.  Hope it helps.

Comment: How do you guarantee that the viewDidLoad method is called (and the notification handler registered) BEFORE the notification is posted?